# Recursively cat all the files into single file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, cat

I have bunch of files sitting in folders like

```
data\A\A\A\json1.json
data\A\A\A\json2.json
data\A\A\B\json1.json
...
data\Z\Z\Z\json_x.json
```

I want to cat all the jsons into one single file?

Comment: The result won't be valid JSON, are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
find data/ -name '*.json' -exec cat {} \; > uber.json
```

a short explanation:

```
find <where> \
  -name <file_name_pattern> \
  -exec <run_cmd_on_every_hit> {} \; \
    > <where_to_store>
```

Comment: Without using find: `cat ./data/*/*/*/*.json > ./all.json`

Comment: Or in `bash` 4 with `shopt -s globstar`, `cat ./data/**/*.json`.

Comment: You should also add "-type f"(only files) to avoid errors when cat tries to print a directory.

Comment: What is \; doing?

Comment: @rwitzel `;` ends the `exec` command.  You need to escape it with `\` though otherwise it would end the entire command.  More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/339015/what-does-mean-in-a-linux-command

Answer (score 18):

Use `find` to get all the JSON files and concatenate them.

```
find data -name '*.json' -exec cat {} + > all.json
```

Note that this will not be valid JSON. If you want a JSON file to contain multiple objects, they need to be in a containing array or object, so you'd need to add `[ ]` around them and put `,` between each one.

Comment: Strictly true, but it would be quite perverse to have directories with `.json` extensions.

Comment: How do you add the ',' chars in the command above between each file?

Comment: @GalBracha Use a `find` command that just prints the filenames, pipe that to a script that reads each filename, does `cat "$filename"; echo ','`.

Comment: You'll then have to edit the file when done to remove the last `,`

Comment: @rwitzel If you end the `-exec` option with `+` instead of `;` it replaces `{}` with all the filenames instead of running the command separately for each filename.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively -- if you have a list of your files -- you can pipe that to `xargs`

```
<path to your files> | xargs cat > all.json
```

Comment: to get a list recursively: find \`pwd\`

Answer (score 9):

```
find ./ -type f | xargs cat > ../singlefilename
```

I would like this ,easy and simple.

`../` avoid the error `input file is output file`.

Comment: `find ./ -type f | fgrep -v singlefilename | xargs cat > ../singlefilename`