# Recursive cat with file names

Tags: bash, recursion, cat

I'd like to cat recursively several files with same name to another file. There's an earlier question "[Recursive cat all the files into single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069173/recursive-cat-all-the-files-into-single-file)" which helped me to get started. However I'd like to achieve the same so that each file is preceded by the filename and path, different files preferably separated with a blank line or ----- or something like that. So the resulting file would read:

```
files/pipo1/foo.txt
flim 
flam 
floo

files/pipo2/foo.txt
plim
plam
ploo
```

Any way to achieve this in bash?

Comment: I've heard of the cat that ate the canary, but I'm having trouble picturing a recursive cat. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! Instead of just `cat`ing the file, you just chain actions to print the filename, cat the file, then add a line feed:

```
find . -name 'foo.txt' \
  -print \
  -exec cat {} \; \
  -printf "\n"
```

Comment: Note that `-printf` is not POSIX. If a POSIX solution is needed, you'll have to replace by `-exec echo \;` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for both you fine gentlepersons, works like a charm :-) @Hot Licks - LOL :D

Comment: `find . -name 'foo.txt' -print -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \;`